# Display upcoming birthdays in Wordpress with ACF - exclude YEAR when query the date picker custom field

Tags: wordpress, datepicker, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields

One of the fields for my custom post type is the member's birthdate, including the year.
However in order to display upcoming birthday, I need to exclude the year form my query, and just use month and day. I was hoping to format the current date and the custom field date to mmdd so I can simply compare them.
The below however take the year in consideration and thus result in 12 March 1963 showing before 18 February 1965 ( simply due to the year )

```
function tsum_home_birthday_widget() { 
// ACF Date Picker Input: j F M   Also tried nd
// ACF Date Picker Output: j F M  Also tried nd 

//$currentdate = date("Y-m-d",mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),date("d"),date("Y")));
//$currentdate = date("nd",mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),date("d"),date("Y")));
$currentdate = date('nd');
$birthDate = get_field('breeder_birthday', false, false);

$meta_query = array (
'key' => 'breeder_birthday',
  // 'key' => $birthDate, // try to use variable so I can chnage the format of the date
'compare' => '<=', // chnage to >= once I know how to exclude the year.
'value' => $currentdate,
'type' => 'DATE',
);


$args = array(
'post_type'   => 'breeders',
'meta_key'  => 'breeder_birthday',
//'meta_key'  => $birthDate, // try to use variable so I can chnage the format of the date
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
'orderby' => 'meta_value',
'order'   => 'ASC',
'posts_per_page'  => '5',
'meta_query' => $meta_query,
);


$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
while( $wp_query->have_posts() )
{
$wp_query->the_post();

?>

<ul class="widget">
<li>

<?php if( get_field('breeder_contact') ): ?>    
    <?php the_field( 'breeder_contact' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if( get_field('breeder_birthday') ): ?>
    <?php
        $bbday = get_field('breeder_birthday', false, false);
        $bbday = new DateTime($bbday);  ?>
    <?php echo $bbday->format('d F Y'); ?>   
<?php endif; ?>

</li>
<hr>
</ul>

<?php 
}
wp_reset_query();
}
add_shortcode('Birthdays', 'tsum_home_birthday_widget');
```